# I want to create an application for logging all my purchases using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, export-to-csv, powershell-5.0

I'm a student and am currently learning PowerShell. I'd like to test to what I've learned by writing various scripts.

I want to log my purchases, and then be able to analysis that data.

I figured creating a CSV file would be best, and so far I've created that with the headers.

```
$csvcontent = @()

$csvcontent+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{Date="";Place_of_Purchase="";Item_Purchased="";Amount_Paid="";Taxes_Paid_on_Item="";Purchase_Method=""}

$csvcontent | Export-Csv $HOME\Desktop\ReceiptData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I then import it back in, which then my question is how can I use `Read-Host` to continually add rows to each header? I've looked around and it seems that it's mostly people statically adding another line of code to add data.

Finally, should I even bother writing this in Powershell as I'm learning Python, Which I presume would make it more adaptable?

Thanks for your guys time, and do note I am a noob!

Comment: PowerShell vs Python is waaay too opinionated. Short answer is no. Learning any language fluently is more important than learning language X over Y. That said, if you want to be in the MS stack, PowerShell IMO is far superior. I've spent time in both, and as long as what I need is only a consideration on Windows I wouldn't even consider Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function Enter-Purchase{

    $CSVContent =New-Object PSObject -Property @{Date="";Place_of_Purchase="";Item_Purchased="";Amount_Paid="";Taxes_Paid_on_Item="";Purchase_Method=""}

    $CSVContent | Get-Member | 
    Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | 
    Select-Object Name | 
    ForEach-Object {$CSVContent.$($_.name) = Read-host "Enter $($_.name)"}

    $CSVContent | export-csv ReceiptData.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation

}

Enter-Purchase
```

This will prompt the user to enter each Note Property of `$CVSContent` and append it to `ReceiptData.csv`